# what is the order of linking in makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

I am newbie in makefile concepts. So feel free to help me in understanding the basics.

```
hellomake:   hello.o hi.o mymain.o
    gcc hello.o hi.o mymain.o
mymain.o:   mymain.c
    gcc -c mymain.c

hello.o:    hello.c
    gcc -c hello.c

hi.o:   hi.c
    gcc -c hi.c
```

If I change the order of the .o files in the target then what is the order of linking that takes place? Remember my `mymain.o` depends on `hello.o` and `hi.o`

Comment: Basically, they are processed int he given order. However, your program should normally not depend on the order. At least for neewbies; there are exceptions - as always.

Answer (score 4):

There's no change in the linking order; make will always run `gcc hello.o hi.o mymain.o` when the .c/.o files change because that's what you told it to do.

Remember that make isn't tied to and has no knowledge of C or linking. It just runs the commands you specify in order to generate the files needed to build a target. In this case, you specified the order `hello.o hi.o mymain.o`, so that's what make will run.

Answer (score 0):

The linker processes files from left to right. It keeps on creating a dynamic list of  unresolved symbols, and uses object (.o) libraries to resolve them. So, you need to first put the static library requiring the symbol, followed by library resolving it.